# find the git repository

Tags: git, repository

I have setup git some time back and havent used it for some time.

Today while following a tutorial for node with express and i ran the following commands

```
1) git init
2) git add .
3) git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

The response i got is

```
"[master (root-commit) 3c87fc5] initial commit
 1449 files changed, 95969 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)"
```

followed by lot of files.

How do i know the actual repository to which the files are committed?

Can some one please help where to find the repository configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository has been created in the directory you ran those commands. The configuration for this repo will be in the `.git/config` file, relative to that directory.

Are you enquiring about the *remote* repository? Since all you've done is create a local repository, you won't have a remote.

Comment: No. This would be necessary if you want to push/pull from/to a repository on a server.

Comment: Thanks it really helped. So i initially thought the commit command will commit to some repository. @Dunni, Thanks(i accidentally deleted the previous comment.)